# Is it possible to source again .bashrc and .zshrc AND remove functions once inside them without restarting?

Tags: zsh, configuration

I had a function inside `.zshrc` that I removed.

Now, when I try to source it, it indeed sources it, but doesn't remove the function that once was inside `.zshrc` from memory.

Is there a way to remove the function (now I believe in memory, in zsh namespace or something like that) without restarting my machine?

Comment: You don't need to restart your machine, obviously. `exec zsh` will get you a fresh shell in the same terminal, directory, environment, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In zsh, you can remove a function with `unhash -f functionname` or `unfunction functionname`.

That doesn't automatically clear functions you've removed from a given startup file, though, because of course the shell doesn't remember where it got it from in the first place and attribute any special meaning to re-sourcing the same file. So you'll have to know what you want to forget.

Since you mention `.bashrc` in the subject: the bash equivalent is `unset -f functioname`

Comment: If a function is binded to a key (bindkey command), is it possible to remove it as well?

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS — if you remove the function without removing the key binding, you'll get `No such shell function \`function'` when you press the key. But perhaps what you want to do is start your key definitions in your dotfile with `bindkey -d`, to reset them to their default state each time before setting up custom things.

Answer (score 1):

`unhash -mf "*"` can be used to clear all functions.
Since it will wipe out the standard zsh goodness functions you will need to reload `/etc/zsh/zshrc`.

I have the following at the beginning of my .zshrc:

```
# Clear all functions and aliases
unhash -mf "*"
unhash -ma "*"
. /etc/zsh/zshrc  # reload standard functions and aliases
```